# Kafka and Python

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

I have a python code that gets data from a API url

```
def get_api_request(zipcode):
    request_url = 'https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<apikey>/info.json/'+ str(zipcode)+'/degrees'
    request = Request(request_url)

    try:
        response = urlopen(request)
        data = response.read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        city=data['city']
        state=data['state']
        update_city(city,state)

    except (Exception) as error:
            print(error)
```

The above code basically gets the city and state for the given zip code. Being new to Kafka, I'm trying to implement this same process through Kafka (to manage large data sets).

Can someone help me in modifying the above code to include Kafka implementation to understand how the Kafka works ?

Comment: What would it even mean to do this "through Kafka"? Exactly what problem are you trying to solve and how do you think Kafka will help you do so?

Comment: I know that Kafka is message queue system. I have 2 source data - one is csv and another is api. I want to have Kafka as a messaging queue to get data from both these sources @DanielRoseman

Comment: yes you can put data from these two sources and can read .So what you want only consumer code or producer as you have only shown reading part.

Comment: @ManishJaiswal Well the data is being produced by the api, so I would need only the consumer part

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about reading messages from a Kafka topic, instead of your existing REST API.

Check out https://www.confluent.io/blog/introduction-to-apache-kafka-for-python-programmers/ and https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python.